# What is the return value of ExecuteNonQuery statement?

Tags: c#

I have written a program to verify username and password using 3 tier architecture in Visual Studio 10. In the DAL, `ExecuteNonQuery` statement returns '-1'. But I want it to return '1' if username and password are correct or '0'if not correct.

Code snipped for DAL:

```
public class LoginDataAccess
{
    SqlConnection con;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localhostakash"].ToString();

    public int LoginData(LoginEntity elOj)
    {
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(constr);
                int result;

                if(ConnectionState.Closed==con.State)
                    con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspuserlogin", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", elOj.Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", elOj.Password);

                result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
    }
}
```

Code snippet for BLL:

```
public class LoginLogic
{
        LoginDataAccess lda = new LoginDataAccess();

        public int userValidate(LoginEntity le)
        {
            int result = 0;

            try
            {
                result = Convert.ToInt32(lda.LoginData(le));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //response.write(ex.Message);
            }

            return result;
        }
}
```

Code snippet for button function:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            LoginLogic ll = new LoginLogic();
            LoginEntity le = new LoginEntity();

            int v;

            le.Username = TextBox1.Text;
            le.Password = TextBox2.Text;

            v = Convert.ToInt32(ll.userValidate(le));

            if (v == 1)
            {
                Label1.Text = "LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY!";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "TRY AGAIN...";
            }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: As I'm a beginner I don't have enough experience on it.So I need your intervention in this context with appropriate code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the documentation:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

You are calling a stored procedure "uspuserlogin". That's why `ExecuteNonQuery` returns -1.

You can return value as row if you need to know result of operation.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspuserlogin]
    @username nvarchar(255),
    @password nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Found 
    FROM [Users]
    WHERE [Username] = @username AND [Password] = @password
END
```

In code:

```
var obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
return (int)obj;

// Somewhere in code
if (loginDataAccess.LoginData(loginEntity) == 1)
    // Authorize
```

Of course, you can transform it to `bool` for your convenience:

```
public bool LoginData(LoginEntity elOj)
{
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        int result;

        if(ConnectionState.Closed==con.State)
            con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspuserlogin", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", elOj.Username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", elOj.Password);

        var obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return ((int)obj > 0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. It was very useful for me. How can i replace that statement.

Comment: I would not use `ExecuteReader`, if all that you are returning is one row with one column use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx), that is what it is designed for.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, you are right. Just a bad habit. Changed the code.

Comment: @ Yeldar Kurmangaliyev I have tried your code. But it shows an error.         It is: "not all code path return a value"

Comment: @AkashK Have you tried the updated code? By the advice of Scott, I have changed it so that uses `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: @ Scott Chamberlain I have tried your option. But I am not successful in that. Can you sort out proper version of this context?

Comment: @ Yeldar Kurmangaliyev Yes I did. But it prompts me the same error which I mentioned in the last message

Comment: @AkashK It works for me well. Also, I don't see any place in my code where it could happen. Show me the stacktrace and the code where this error happen.

Comment: @ Yeldar Kurmangaliyev Now I have cleared my errors. But still it is not returning expected value.